# Changing WiX command line with Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio, command-line, wix

When building my WiX project through Visual Studio, I can see a pre-generated string of command line arguments passed to the WiX compiler in the output console.

I've searched around the web and this site to no avail, but I'm looking to manually edit the command line arguments on a per project basis when I build my WiX Project through Visual Studio 2010. Something like the C++ projects where you can manually edit the command line.

I'm using the Wix Toolset Visual Studio 2010 Extension and WiX v3.

Comment: If you deep dive into the wix2010.targets file you can see how all the command line arguments are built. It's pretty complicated though but a good exercise if you want to learn more about MSBuild and how WiX works.

Comment: @BrianSutherland exactly what I was looking for. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the answer, Brian Sutherland's answer suffices, and you can explore the WiX.target files (which ultimately point to the wix2010.target file in this instance) for changing the MSBuild information.

Comment: where are these .target files?